# Second order ODE with piecewise term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $\frac{d^2 n}{d z^2} + 2 \frac{dn}{dz} + f(n) = 0$, where $f(n) = \begin{cases} n, \quad 0 \leq n \leq \frac{1}{2} \\ 1 - n, \quad \frac{1}{2} \leq n \leq 1 \end{cases}$.

I am confused about how to handle the $f(n)$ term. I believe it should be solved in cases, say $0 \leq n \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2} \leq n \leq 1$, like this:

If $0 \leq n \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{d^2 n}{d z^2} + 2 \frac{dn}{dz} + n = 0$, which has solution $n(z) = c_1 e^{-z} + c_2 z e^{-z}$.

If $\frac{1}{2} \leq n \leq 1$, then $\frac{d^2 n}{d z^2} + 2 \frac{dn}{dz} + 1-n = 0$ which has solution $n(z) = c_3e^{(-1+\sqrt{2})z} + c_4 e^{(-1 - \sqrt{2})z} + 1$.

Would I write the final answer as $$n(z) =
  \begin{cases}
  C_1e^{-z} + C_2 z e^{-z}, \quad & 0 \leq n \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
  C_3e^{(-1+\sqrt{2})z} + C_4 e^{(-1 - \sqrt{2})z} + 1, & \frac{1}{2} \leq n \leq 1
  \end{cases}?
  $$

I am uncomfortable with this because the answer seems "circular" to me because the name of the solution is $n$ but the conditions are on $n$ and not $z$.

Comment: I am confused. So if  say $n=\frac{1}{4}$ then what does $\frac{d^2 n}{d z^2}$ mean?  i.e. What does $\frac{d^2 \frac{1}{4}}{d z^2}$  mean?  How can the dependent variable be a number?

Comment: @Nasser I have no idea... that's part of what I'm confused. The material I typed in the post came from a homework I turned in months ago for a class and my professor accepted it without comment. Now I'm studying for a qual and can't make sense of what should have happened. Does it make sense for PDEs? What if we had $\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = f(n) + \frac{\partial^2n}{\partial x^2}$ with the same $f(n)$ as defined in my post. I have that PDE written down in a textbook and an old qualifying exam but the question you have posed doesn't make sense to me in that context either.

Comment: You must copied something wrong. The dependent variable can't be a number. Not for PDE's either. It looks like $n$ is a separate parameter and the ODE dependent variable is something else.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the sanity check. This is a screenshot of the PDE that appears in the textbook we use https://imgur.com/RKaYf9e in case you are curious. (I don't have a textbook source for the ODE in my post since it was motivated by a solution I wrote to a HW).

Comment: OK, I see. A little confusing way of writing it. But if that is the case, then what you did looks OK to me. For each range of $n$ You have a different ODE. btw, you have a little typo there, you wrote one solution in the middle using $t$ instead of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $u=\dfrac{dn}{dz}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2n}{dz^2}=\dfrac{du}{dz}=\dfrac{du}{dn}\dfrac{dn}{dz}=u\dfrac{du}{dn}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}u\dfrac{du}{dn}+2u+n=0,\quad0\leq n\leq\dfrac{1}{2}\\u\dfrac{du}{dn}+2u+1-n=0,\quad\dfrac{1}{2}\leq n\leq1\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{du}{dn}=-2-\dfrac{n}{u},\quad0\leq n\leq\dfrac{1}{2}\\\dfrac{du}{dn}=\dfrac{n-1}{u}-2,\quad\dfrac{1}{2}\leq n\leq1\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{n}{u+n}+\ln(u+n)=c_1,\quad0\leq n\leq\dfrac{1}{2}\\(2-\sqrt2)\ln((\sqrt2-1)(n-1)-u)+(2+\sqrt2)\ln((\sqrt2+1)(n-1)+u)=c_2,\quad\dfrac{1}{2}\leq n\leq1\end{cases}$